# I am running window 8.1 and I can't open any Microsoft office applications.

Tags: microsoft-office

I am running window 8.1 and I can't open any Microsoft office applications.  I keep getting a message that says the application was unable to start correctly 0xc0000142

Comment: Tried reinstalling?

Comment: [Repair Office programs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/repair-office-programs-HA010357402.aspx)

Comment: [Why can’t I start my Office 2013 application?](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Why-can-t-I-start-my-Office-2013-application--52bd7985-4e99-4a35-84c8-2d9b8301a2fa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Were you able to open it before? Have you rebooted? What have you tried or researched on your own? Please read [ask] and update your question for we can effectively help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall Office 2013
- Run a `SFC /scannow` via command prompt
- Install Office 2013